# Не могу перегрузить оператор +

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов

Проблема заключается в том, что раньше я перегружал таким методом, а с шаблонными функциями это, как я понял, работает по-другому. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем заключается моя ошибка.
Мой код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

template <class Type1, class Type2>
class myclass {
    Type1 i; Type2 j;
public:
    myclass(Type1 a, Type2 b)
    {
        i = a; j = b;
    }
    void show()
    {
        cout << i << ' ' << j << '\n';
    }
    friend myclass operator + (myclass& o1, myclass& o2);
};
myclass operator + (myclass& o1, myclass& o2) 
{
    return myclass(*this);
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    myclass<int,double> object(10,10.2);
    object.show();
}
```

Выдает ошибку: отсутствует список аргументов для шаблон класса "myclass".

Comment: Ну прям образцовый пример. Позвольте начать с того, что: зачем вы тяните эту кучу барахла в виде хидеров?  Вы же большую часть не используете, не говоря о том, что как минимум conio.h - платмормозависимый. Далее: не используйте `using namespace std`. Зачем вам настройка локали? Вы же не выводите кирилицу или типа того. Почему параметры operator+ - не константные? Откуда this в свободной функции? Это ж не метод. Раз myclass шаблон с одним параметром, то почему вы этот факт полностью игнорируете в вашей функции? Вы обязаны указать шаблонный параметр (или несколько) для этой функции

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код для её воспроизведения**

Answer (score 1):

Как обычно и бывает в подобных вопросах, **в тексте ошибки всё сказано**. Не стоит недооценивать компилятор, он всё правильно нашёл. И предполагаю, что даже указал строчку, в которой находится проблема. Вот эту:

```cpp
myclass operator + (myclass& o1, myclass& o2)
```

Теперь осталось сложить в уме текст ошибки и содержание данной строки и можно прийти к выводу, что функция в данном случае описана отдельно от описания класса, а значит, во-первых, перед ней необходимо указать, что она шаблонная с помощью ключевого слова `template`.

А во-вторых, `myclass`, использованный в данной функции, – шаблонный класс. А раз так, то он требует указания аргументов шаблона, что и написано в тексте ошибки.

В итоге, код функции примет следующий вид:

```cpp
template <class Type1, class Type2>
myclass<Type1, Type2> operator + (myclass<Type1, Type2>& o1, myclass<Type1, Type2>& o2)
{
    return myclass(*this);
}
```

Comment: А то что дружественные Функции не имеют указателя this?

Comment: @mik.ov, каюсь, тут действовал по принципу "Работает – не трогай".